# in ASOP build need to update/delete list from setting

Tags: android, android-source

[image]

I want to remove "Battery" header , from setting screen list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I want to remove Battery level, icon and description "100%" from setting screen, "showing above image" , I have complete ASOP source code. I am trying to find in this path "https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/refs/heads/master"

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies here :https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/rros

You can override any layout by creating a Runtime Ressource Overlay package that can be "installed" through ADB or included as a package in your AOSP build. Most likely you'll want to select the parent XML of the settings list and its child removing battery.

Comment: I think Settings app uses dynamic list on that screen, and it's unlikely RRO can help. But I didn't know about RRO, interesting